# unable to get org.grails.plugins.wsclient.service.WebService in src/groovy?

Tags: web-services, grails, groovy

I am trying to create a webservice class in src/groovy but it gives error and complains no webservice found.
Please help why i am not getting in src/groovy.

```
import org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit
import org.grails.plugins.wsclient.service.WebService
class ConnectWebservice {
WebService webService   ///it complains that not found.

def static wsHandleMap = [:]
def static handle

 static def getProxy =  {url->
           def wsdlURL = url+"?wsdl"
        def proxy = webService.getClient(wsdlURL)  ////not get webService
        proxy?.initialize()

        proxy.metaClass.getCxfClient = { ->
            delegate.client
        }

        // get client instance
        def cxfClient = proxy.cxfClient
        // create new endpoint url
        URL newUrl = new URL(url)
        // assign new created url to the client
        cxfClient.getConduit().getTarget().getAddress().setValue(newUrl.toExternalForm());
        //Extra: to set timeout, use:
        proxy.client.conduit.clientSidePolicy.setReceiveTimeout(999)
        proxy.client.conduit.clientSidePolicy.setConnectionTimeout(999)

        //println proxy

        return proxy
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it working.changed the line -

```
def proxy = webService.getClient(wsdlURL)
```

TO

```
def proxy = new WSClient(wsdlURL,this.class.classLoader)
```

Answer (score 1):

So this is inside `src/groovy`?

Services don't get injected into files found in `src/groovy` by default.

To get this working, you should consider making this class a Service (easiest route if possible), or else you will need to [register the class](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Dependency-Injection-for-classes-in-src-groovy-td2258005.html) as a Spring bean to that required services and classes get injected

PS:  You have installed the WSClient plugin right?

Comment: Thanks Tim. i got it working.changed the line -                                   def proxy = webService.getClient(wsdlURL)   TO           def proxy = new WSClient(wsdlURL,this.class.classLoader)